# How turn off focus?

Tags: xaml, xamarin

How turn off focus on the brand and color? I was previously selected color or brand and then type registrations

```
private void InitializePage()
{
    RegistrationNumberEntry.Completed += (s, e) => BrandListPicker.Focus();
    BrandListPicker.SelectedIndexChanged += (s, e) => ColorListPicker.Focus();

    BindingContext = new RegisterDetailsPageViewModel(Navigation);
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but could you set the focus to the page instead?

Comment: You can use `Focusable = false` if you don't want the elements to be focused if that's what you're looking for, but I don't understand the question fully

Comment: I choose the brand and I will return to field and enter the number and press enter I do not wont focus again to brand